# Cannot access a non-shared member of a class in C#, but can in VB?

Tags: c#

I`m just started learning C#, used to be a VB programmer.

In VB.NET, it is possible to access a form class method, even if this method is not declared as **shared**.
In the code below, I don`t get compiler errors, and calling the method **Foo** inside **ClassFoo** works ok.

```
Public Class Form1
    Public Sub Foo()
        MsgBox("Test")
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class ClassFoo
    Sub Foo()
        Form1.Foo()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Then, I tried to port the same code to C#, but I get an error: 
"An object reference is required for non-static field and bla bla bla".

Why I can access a method not shared in VB and can`t in C#?

Comment: can you post your ported code?

Comment: What is your c# code that isn't working?

Comment: I have no idea what the VB.NET code is doing. It's certainly not accessing the instance method `Foo` of the `Form1` class, unless `Form1` is also the name of an instance, or unless it magically creates an instance when the class is being referenced. Did you actually _run_ the VB.NET code? If so, try running it in the debugger and stepping into the call to `Foo`.

Comment: Did you really intend to say `Class Form1` -- or did you mean `Module Form1` (which is a `static class` in C#, btw.)? Because you *cannot* access a non-static method without an object instance.

Comment: @John: Form1 is the class name, not an class object instance or module name.
I`ve run the code, and it works ok. Everything works ok, but only in VB.net, in C# i get compiler error.

Comment: I meant for you to step into it with the debugger. See if there's a real instance present.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a rather horrific feature inherited from VB6, a language that allowed this construct.  It is not allowed in a pure OOP language, referencing a member of an object requires an object name, not a type name.

The VB.NET team went through some trouble to make this work in the VB.NET language.  "Form1" in this statement is in fact an object reference, one that gets auto-generated by the compiler.  Something that goes horribly wrong when that name is used in threads btw.

But this won't fly in the C# language, you *have* to supply an object reference.  You will have to re-factor the code so the ClassFoo object has that reference.  Something like this:

```
public class Form1 {
    ClassFoo fooObj;
    public Form1() {
        fooObj = new ClassFoo(this);
    }
    public void Foo() {
        MessageBox.Show("un-fooed");
    }
}

public class ClassFoo {
    Form1 mainForm;
    public ClassFoo(Form1 main) {
        mainForm = main;
    }
    public void Foo() {
        mainForm.Foo();
    }
}
```

This is probably going to cause some pain while you are learning C#.  The Q&D workaround for this is to use Application.OpenForms.  Avoid using it if you prefer to byte the bullet.

Comment: Yup, there's a lot of VB.NET that's not visible.  Syntax sugar, not always sweet.

Comment: Just set the project to have Option Explicit and Option Strict On!  At least it isn't a feature of the language (but rather the compiler).

Comment: Lol "byte" the bullet

Answer (score 3):

In C# `Shared` is actually `Static`

Your port should be:

```
public class Form1
{
   public static void Foo()
   {
       MessageBox.Show("Test");
   }
}

public class ClassFoo
{
   public void Foo()
   {
      Form1.Foo();
   }
}
```

Static methods / fields / properties / etc don't require an instance to use, they are members of the class itself. Another Example:

```
public class MyClass
{
    protected MyClass() { /* Do Something */ }
    public static MyClass Create(string someParam)
    {
        /* Do something with someParam */
        return new MyClass();
    }
}
```

Then:

```
MyClass a = new MyClass(); // Error, Constructor is protected
MyClass b = MyClass.Create("Foobar"); // Works, calls the `static` method
```

---

**Update: In response to your comment:**

`<snarky-answer>`Because vb is horrible?`</snarky-answer>` No really, this looks like a disaster waiting to happen.

If you dont declare your sub as shared, and you try to access instance variables, it'll blow up. In C# if you try to access non-static members from a static method, it'll give you a compile time error, and thus such bad code doesn't make it into production.

As for *why* you can do it, that's a question for the Microsoft Team. The real thing is that you *shouldn't* do it!

---

For the record, I tried to compile your code:

[image: http://i47.tinypic.com/2qco61k.png]

Comment: Hi @Aren. I know it`s static. But why in VB the code works without Shared?
And I have another problem. My static method must have non static members, and I don`t know how can I call the method because compiler generates an error.

Comment: Updated to answer your comment.

Comment: Oh my God... in my VB it works, compiles and behaves as expected... have no idea why in you VB and Josh VB it`s not compiling.

Comment: This is common VB.NET syntax and accepted by the compiler. In a Windows Forms project.

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't be able to in VB. I copied and pasted your sample vb code and it gives the same compile error.

Shared in VB is Static in C# Aside from the keyword, the behavior is the same. If you want to access a member without creating an instance of that class, it needs to be static (shared in vb).

Comment: In my VB its working exactly as I posted.
Using Visual Studio 2008 Express Edition.

Comment: @RHaguiuda: I call shenanigans!

Comment: @RHaguiuda: Must be a VB express thing.  I get compiler errors in VS 2008 pro.  Bottom line, if Foo() changes state, make an instance. If Foo() doesnt, make it static. Calling non-static members statically shouldn't work. And if it does work, it shouldn't be done.

Comment: @RHaguiuda: try to right-click the solution or project and choose "Show all files". Poke around and maybe you'll see the invisible ... stuff.

Comment: This is common VB.NET syntax and accepted by the compiler.  In a Windows Forms project.